# In spark (2.4 and above), how to completely "redact" ALL sensitive information

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

In (py)spark 2.4, it is possible to redact some sensitive informations from the event logs, for exemple:

```
    .config("spark.eventLog.enabled", "true") \
    .config("spark.eventLog.dir", "hdfs:///tmp/spark-events") \
    .config("spark.redaction.regex", os.environ["SPARK_REDACTION_REGEX"]) \
```

This would remove "all" informations from the spark event logs, at least from the `SparkListenerEnvironmentUpdate` event.

However, when checking the event file, there are still some sensitive data, matching the regex, that are not redacted.

For example, in the `SparkListenerJobStart` event.

How would I "redact" ALL the informations, for ALL the events ?

Comment: this is a good question! if there isn't anything native in pyspark that can redact information in event logs, this could easily be a feature request

Comment: @DerekO I'm gonna dig in spark3 and if nothing comes to me, I'll go and check/make a SPIP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not seem possible in (py)spark 2. However, This is fixed in spark 3.1. Indeed, all variables matching the redaction regex are correctly redacted.

Comment: Do you have any reference/JIRA?

Comment: Nothing I can remember of/find, except my own experiments.